# Wild card App id + In app purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have an app that is in the app store currently. Now i want to add in app purchase in the app and my app id is  like  A1B2C3D4E5.* this. I followed the apple 's instructions to  change wild card app id to explicit id.

Link:-
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1680/_index.html.

Then i created provisional profile using explicit app id but when i tried to select provisional profile  in the Code Signing Identity section of your Target's Build pane in Xcode
i am unable to find proper matches to the provisional profile.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the app identifier (part after A1B2C3D4E5) is identical to the app identifier set in the Xcode project.

Comment: you mean to say bundle identifier in the info.plist